# Java dynamically add a button to a panel

Tags: java

I have a panel, and a button1. When I press the button, I want to create other buttons (of certain height and width) inside the panel. So I press the button1 once, it creates a button in the panel. I press button1 again, it creates another button in the panel right next to the other button or with some space in-between. Any help? I tried

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
           JButton jButton = new JButton("Button");
           panel1.add(jButton);
           validate();
        
    }
```

Comment: Where do you want each extra button to appear on the panel? Do you want them in a row, one next to the other? Do you want them in a column, one under (or above) the other? Do you want them in a grid? Maybe you could post some kind of drawing or image that illustrates what you want?

Comment: Hello, I want the buttons to appear in a Row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that does what you desire.
It uses [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) to ensure that the buttons are displayed in a single row.
It sets each button to the same, particular size.
There is the same size gap between each, adjacent button.
It uses a [JScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) so that once you add more buttons that can fit into the width of the `JScrollPane`, you can scroll to see the other buttons. This is instead of increasing the size of the `JPanel` (or creating a new row) each time you add a button.

More explanations after the code.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class AdButton implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private static final String  ADD = "Add";
    private static final String  EXIT = "Exit";

    private int  counter;
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JPanel  panel;

    @Override // java.awt.event.ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case ADD:
                addButton();
                break;
            case EXIT:
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                              actionCommand,
                                              "Unhandled",
                                              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        createGui();
    }

    private void addButton() {
        panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        JButton button = new JButton(String.valueOf(++counter));
        Dimension size = new Dimension(50, 30);
        button.setMaximumSize(size);
        button.setMinimumSize(size);
        button.setPreferredSize(size);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.revalidate();
    }

    private JButton createButton(String text, int mnemonic, String tooltip) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
        button.setToolTipText(tooltip);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        return button;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(createButton(ADD, KeyEvent.VK_A, "Add button to panel"));
        buttonsPanel.add(createButton(EXIT, KeyEvent.VK_X, "Exit the application"));
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private void createGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Add Buttons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JScrollPane createPanel() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        LayoutManager mgr = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS);
        panel.setLayout(mgr);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel, 
                                                 ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
                                                 ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 100));
        return scrollPane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new AdButton());
    }
}
```

You should use an [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) rather than a `MouseListener` when you want an action to be performed as a result of clicking in a `JButton`.

The important part in the `addButton()` method is the call to `revalidate()` which makes the `JPanel` layout all its components and draw them on the screen. You need to do this since you have added another component to the `JPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you already have access to the panel considering you are trying to access it from inside the method.

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
            JButton button = new JButton("Button");
            button.setVisible(true);                 
            panel1.add(button);
            panel1.revalidate();
    }
```

To choose a specific location for your button it all depends on what type of layout the JPanel has.

I believe the FlowLayout (which is the default layout for a JPanel) should place the button next to each other in a row until it's parent container has no more room horizontally according to it's parent, then it will start on the next row.

A guide to layouts by Oracle can be found [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)